# Observer Pattern: Internal vs. External Registration

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

What is be the best choice to register an observer? I did not find anything on this subject. Mostly "push vs. pull" is discussed, but there are also a couple of options to register an observer.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Subject subject = new ConcreteSubject();
    // External registration
    Observer observerExternal = new ConcreteObserverExternal();
    subject.registerObserver(observerExternal);
    // Internal registration, option 1
    Observer observerInternal1 = new ConcreteObserverInternal1(subject);
    // Internal registration, option 2
    ConcreteObserverInternal2 observerInternal2 = new ConcreteObserverInternal2(subject);
}

interface Observer
{
    void inform();
}
class ConcreteObserverExternal implements Observer
{
    @Override
    public void inform()
    {
        // do sth.
    }
}
class ConcreteObserverInternal1 implements Observer
{
    public ConcreteObserverInternal1(Subject subject)
    {
        subject.registerObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void inform()
    {
        // do sth.
    }
}
class ConcreteObserverInternal2
{
    public ConcreteObserverInternal2(Subject subject)
    {
        subject.registerObserver(() -> inform());
    }

    private void inform()
    {
        // do sth.
    }
}
interface Subject
{
    void registerObserver(Observer obs);

    void unregisterObserver(Observer obs);
}
class ConcreteSubject implements Subject
{
    @Override
    public void registerObserver(Observer obs)
    {
        // register
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterObserver(Observer obs)
    {
        // unregister
    }

    private void foo()
    {
        // ...
        notifyObservers();
    }

    private void notifyObservers()
    {
        // notify observers
    }
}
```

Here are three cases I have in my code:

- An observer is registered at program start and is never unregistered. In this case, all of the 3 options would be possible.
- An observer is registered somewhere and needs to be unregistered when some external event occurs. The observer does not know about this external event and obviously it must be registered externally (option 1).
- An observer is registered somewhere and needs to be unregistered when some external event occurs. The observer knows what happened, because it is also an observer of this external event. In this case, all of the 3 options would be possible.

**In the cases where all 3 options are possible, which one is the best from an OO and clean-code point of view?**

Here is a list of some pros and cons I think each option has.

**1. External registration**

*Pros*:
 - Less parameters in the constructor of the observer.
 - Subject does not need to be abstracted to promote loose coupling between Subject and Observer.

*Cons*:
 - One must not forget to register the observer in the client code.  
 - Client code is responsible for registration.

*Neutral*:
 - The observer has an additional public method.
 - Observer can be registered / unregistered by client code.

**2. Internal registration, option 1: Concrete observer implements the Observer interface**

*Pros*:
 - Observer is responsible for registration.
 - Registration cannot be *forgotten*, because one is forced to pass the Subject  to the Observer's constructor.

*Cons*:
 - One more parameter in the constructor of the observer.

*Neutral*:
 - The observer has an additional public method.
 - Observer can be registered / unregistered by client code.
 - Observer can register / unregister itself.

**3. Internal registration, option 2: Concrete observer does NOT implement the Observer interface**

*Pros*:
 - Observer is responsible for registration.
 - Registration cannot be *forgotten*, because one is forced to pass the Subject  to the Observer's constructor.
 - Observer does not have an additional public method that could be abused by anything not related to "Subject notifying Observer".

*Cons*:
 - One more parameter in the constructor of the observer.

*Neutral*:
 - Observer can only register / unregister itself.

Comment: Excellent observations and overview! Thanks. My programming is filled with weighing pros and cons in individual situations — I believe this is just one more instance of the same, so I’d avoid rules and try to make the best choice from situation to situation. Your post will be of help in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Given the subtle differences you raised between 'external' and 'internal' registrations, it looks like there won't be one right answer. Still, I'll try.

I'd prefer 'external' registration to other two for two reasons:

- The `Observer`s don't know anything about the `Subject`s; i.e., they are fairly decoupled. For e.g., I can attach one `Observer` to multiple `Subject`s, and no one would have to change.
- More in line with the Single Responsibility principle. The `Observer` only cares about what it needs to do when `inform`ed. It doesn't care about registering/unregistering with anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like your second point. Regarding the first one, I could imagine to pass a list of Subjects to the Observer.

Comment: Yes, you could pass a list of `Subject`s, but that would introduce lot of unhealthy coupling between the two.